# finding equation of plane that makes an angle with another plane

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a plane $P$ that passes through the $z-axis$ and makes an angle of $60^{\circ}$ with the plane $2x + y - \sqrt{5} z - 7 = 0$. What is the equation of plane $P$?

What I tried: We are looking for a plane $Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$. We are given that the angle between vectors $(A,B,C)$ and the normal of given plane $(2,1,-\sqrt{5})$ is $60^{\circ}$. From here I get an equations involving $A,B,C$. Also, we know since plane passes trough $z-axis$ that the points $(0,0,z_0)$ and $(1,0,z_1)$ lie on the plane. I think this will give us $A$ and $B$ but still stuck on finding $C$ and $z_i$. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we know since plane passes trough $z-axis$ that the points $(0,0,z_0)$ and $(1,0,z_1)$ lie on the plane

I don't understand what you are doing. If the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ passes through $z$-axis, then the plane passes through points $(0,0,0),(0,0,1)$, from which we have $C=D=0$.

The plane makes an angle of $60^\circ$ with the plane $2x+y-\sqrt 5\ z-7=0$, so
$$\cos 60^\circ=\frac{2A+B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-\sqrt 5)^2}},$$
i.e.
$$\sqrt{10(A^2+B^2)}=2(2A+B)\tag1$$

Suppose here that $A=0$. Then, we get $B=0$, a contradiction. So, $A\not=0$, and so we may set $A=1$. Solving $(1)$ for $B$ gives $B=3,-1/3$.

Thus, the answer is
$$x+3y=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad x-\frac 13y=0$$

Comment: How do u know it passes thru the origin?

Comment: @user135395: "The plane passes through $z$-axis" means that $z$-axis is on the plane, in other words, $z$-axis is included in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

HINT...if the required plane contains the $z$ axis, then it must be of the form $$Ax+By=0$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that for all $z$, $(0,0,z)$ is in our plane (the $z$-axis). In particular,
$(0,0,0)$ is in the plane, so we must have
$$
A\cdot0+B\cdot0+C\cdot0+D=0\implies 0+0+0+D=0\implies D=0.
$$
Then, for all $z$, we must have
$$
A\cdot0+B\cdot0+C\cdot z=0\implies 0+0+Cz=0\implies C=0.
$$
Therefore the equation of the plane is of the form
$$
Ax+By=0.
$$
Then our normal vector is of the form $(A,B,0)$.

Let $(a,b,0)$ be the unit vector in the same direction as $(A,B,0)$. As you noted, the angle between $(a,b,0)$ and $(2,1,−\sqrt{5})$ is $60$ degrees, so we must have
$$
(a,b,0)\cdot(2,1,−\sqrt{5})=2a+b=\cos(60deg)||(a,b,0)||||(2,1,−\sqrt{5})||=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10},
$$
since $(a,b,0)$ is a unit vector.

From here we can solve for $b$ in terms of $a$, and using the fact that
$a^2+b^2=1$, we can solve this quadratic equation for $a$. The plane we are looking for is then
$ax+by=0$.